# Print function prints results twice

Tags: python, range

I'm not sure why print function prints the results twice when I execute this simple code below:

```
def multiplier(number):
        y = number
        for i in range(y):
            x = i * 7
            if x < y:
                print(x)
            else:
                ""
            
multiplier(100)
```

Comment: It only prints each line once for me. How are you running the script?

Comment: Same printing only once, (0
7
14
21
28
35
42
49
56
63
70
77
84
91
98
)

Comment: first, check your question and then post it here.
it prints each line once also for me.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far. Often while you prepare a very good question and an MWE (minimal working example) you will find the answer by yourself. But for our learning please let us know what the problem was.

Comment: You can also delete the `else: ""` since it serves no purpose.  Also, the normal way to create a do-nothing statement is to use the `pass` statement, not an empty string (but as mentioned, you don't need any of that here, it's just useless clutter in your case).

Comment: Have you considered that once x >= y then that state will persist for all future iterations. Therefore, instead of *else: ""* try *else: break*